# Remapping TAB Key in BioShock Infinite?

Tags: bioshock-infinite

Is there a way to remap the TAB key? It won't do it through the in-game GUI because it says it's reserved, even though it does the same thing as the escape key. Is it possible to do it through editing a .ini file? I found where the key bindings are in the "Documents\My Games\BioShock Infinite\XGame\Config\XInput.ini" file, but I can't find the key binding for the "navigate to goal" key, which is default to "N". How would I change the binding from "N" to "TAB" through the .ini file?

Comment: Infinite was notorious for not allowing easy rebinds. I typically rebind the movement keys, and I remember when I first played it, it broke a ton of other functions. I had to use a controller just to switch ammo types, while still using m&k for movement and looking around.

Answer (score 2):

No, I ran into the same issue as you did during my playthrough this weekend. The tab key is strangely tied down and cannot be rebound unless you install a third party key changing application.